# Remove Featured tab hover un-required link reference

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, tooltips, bountied-tab

The feature tab in [main page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) on mouse hover shows as below.

> [image]

```html
<a href="?tab=featured" title="Looking for more featured questions? Browse the &lt;a href=&amp;quot;/questions?sort=featured&amp;quot;&gt;complete list&lt;/a&gt;.">featured</a>
```

However, you can see there is un-required link reference to feature-tab. Instead it should be as simple as **Looking for more featured questions? Browse the complete list.**       <sub>without link ref*</sub>

Or like in [question/feature tab hover](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) **Questions with open bounties.**

Note:- Link provided in tooltip is completely useless there and serves no purpose..

Comment: I bet it was localization! Caching is slacking lately...

Comment: Oh, not another double-encoding bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some copy-pasta error during localization (hey [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson), you [were right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196959/remove-featured-tab-hover-un-required-link-reference#comment622638_196959)!).

The wrong description for this tab was used. Whoops.

Fixed in the next build.

Thanks for noticing and reporting!